# Kubernetes Connection refused

Tags: docker, kubectl

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-deployment-example
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-deployment-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pod1
        image: velpegor/assignment2_apache_web:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      - name: pod2
        image: velpegor/assignment2_mysql_db:1.0
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        emptyDir: {}
```

this is YAML file

```
image : velpegor/assignment2_apache_web:1.0
-> 
FROM php:7.3-apache

COPY index.php /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND

image : velpegor/assignment2_mysql_db:1.0

FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="1234"
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE "LeeWJ"
ENV MYSQL_USER "LeeWonJun"
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD "1234"

EXPOSE 3306 
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqYir.png)

Does anyone know what should I need to do to fix that?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Comment: Can you confirm what have you done that caused the error of Kubernetes connection refused?

Comment: what you want to fix first ? looks like kubectl running and all pod are also running as deployment status is running so.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that you database working correctly I suggest to make :

```sh
kubectl port-forward <your-pods> OR <your-service-name> -p <host-port> <pod-port>
```

example in your case:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/pod1 80 80
```

And then open an utility like **MySQL workbench** and try to connect , keep trying until connection established , and if you have a question thanks to ask me again or add error logs on comment .